# Difference between "related to" and "associated with"

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

What is the difference between associated with and related to such as:

> This degree is (related in / associated with) an increase.

Comment: 'related in' would not be grammatically correct here, but 'related to' would be.

Answer (score -1):

Related can mean a positive connection, or a negative connection, but associated would usually mean only a positive connection.